# flutter gives error "The method 'validate' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: validate()" even though having key and Form Widget

Tags: flutter

I am trying to validate my textFormField which i have set on the appbar as in the code shown bellow. while clicking on the submit (floating button) it gives me error "The method 'validate' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: validate()"

```
                appbar: AppBar(
                bottom:preferredSize(
                     child:Form(
                  child: TextFormField(
                    key: _taskformKey,
                    validator: (task) {
                      if (task == null || task.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Text is empty';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    onSaved: (String task) {
                      task = this.task;
                    },
                    controller: taskText,
                    
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Remind me to..",
                      
                  ),
                 ),
                ),


my floating button where i call validate

 floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      if (_taskformKey.currentState.validate()) {
        _taskformKey.currentState.save();

        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `_taskformKey` is a `GlobalKey<FormState>` you need to pass it to `Form.key`, not `TextFormField.key`, as it is a form's key.

Refer to this guide for some tips on using forms and validators: [Build a form with validation - Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation)